# Dúvida sobre como usar o inner join

Tags: sql, join, inner

Tenho 4 tabelas no meu banco de dados

```
Tabela Cadastro
     - idCadastro(PK)
     - IP

Tabela Porta
     - idPorta(PK)
     - numero porta
     - idSwitch(FK)

Tabela Porta_has_Cadastro
     - idCadastro(FK)
     - idPorta(PK)

//Observação: Relaçao n para n entre cadastro e porta.

Tabela Switch
     - idSwitch
     - Modelo
```

Quero que as informações apareçam assim:

```
IP  ----  PORTA  ----  SWITCH
```

Exemplo:

```
O ip 192.168.0.1 esta na porta 1 do Switch HP
O ip 192.168.0.2 esta na porta 2 do Switch Dell
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tenta esta query:

```sql
SELECT cad.IP,
        por.numero_porta,
        swi.modelo
FROM cadastro cad
  INNER JOIN Porta_has_Cadastro phc ON cad.idCadastro = phc.idCadastro
  INNER JOIN Porta por ON phc.id_porta = por.id_porta
  INNER JOIN Switch swi ON por.id_switch = swi.id_switch
```

Depois se quiser trazer a frase completa direta do banco, pode usar concatenação de string, mais ai depende do tipo de dados de cada coluna, podendo ser necessária conversão do tipo, já a concatenação depende do banco de dados, dos que sei, pode ser + para Sql Server e || para Postgres.

Comment: Correção:  a tabela switch não tem o idPorta. Na verdade, a tabela porta tem o idSwitch

Comment: mas já adaptei e deu certo. Mto obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

[Assumindo MSSQLServer]

Sem especificar qual das duas formas quer, pode fazer o seguinte:

```sql
SELECT 'O ip ' + C.IP + ' esta na porta ' + CAST(P.numero_porta AS nvarchar) + ' do Switch ' + s.Model
FROM dbo.Switch as s
     inner join dbo.Porta as P on p.idSwitch = s.idSwitch
     inner join dbo.Porta_has_Cadastro as PhC on PhC.idPorta = p.idPorta
     inner join dbo.Cadastro as C on C.idCadastro = PhC.idCadastro;
```

Ou então:

```sql
SELECT C.IP, P.numero_porta, s.Model
FROM dbo.Switch as s
     inner join dbo.Porta as P on p.idSwitch = s.idSwitch
     inner join dbo.Porta_has_Cadastro as PhC on PhC.idPorta = p.idPorta
     inner join dbo.Cadastro as C on C.idCadastro = PhC.idCadastro;
```

Veja um [exemplo no SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/89f40/2).

Comment: Correção:  a tabela switch não tem o idPorta. Na verdade, a tabela porta tem o idSwitch

Comment: @GuilhermeDuarte actualizei o código para corresponder as mudanças do *schema*

Comment: Muito bom . Obrigado !!